# How do I implement dynamic mapping (RKDynamicMapping) with this JSON?

Tags: mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

My backend returns this kind of JSON files:

{
    "response": {
        "message": "Test"
    },
    "responseCode": 205
}

Depending on responseCode value, what is inside response is different.
I know I have to use something like RKDynamicMapping, but not sure how.
The problem I see is that in the sample code and manual, the attribute to differentiate among mappings is inside, but in this case is outside.
I tried this but doesn't work:

```
    [dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
        NSNumber* responseCode=(NSNumber*)representation[@"responseCode"];
        if (responseCode.integerValue==204) {
            return searchByLocatorResponseContent204Mapping;
        } else if (responseCode.integerValue==205) {
            return searchByLocatorResponseContent205Mapping;
        }
        return nil;
    }];
    RKResponseDescriptor *searchByLocatorResponseContentResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dynamicMapping pathPattern:kCheckinSearchByLocatorPath keyPath:nil  statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:searchByLocatorResponseContentResponseDescriptor];
```

I guess because the mapping I want to change doesn't containt the attribute to distinguish them (like type in girls/boys sample code from rest kit website)

Does anyone have any recommendation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not use the keypath to specify the mapping for the items inside 'response'?

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up like this, restkit expects the `dynamicMapping` will provide mapping for the whole response json, not just the contents of 'response'.

Basically `searchByLocatorResponseContent204Mapping` needs to have mapping for the `response` field and the `responseCode` field.

As far as I know, restkit cannot look outward, since the `representation` parameter only gives you info for inside the current context. However, it is on the road map and there is a ticket about this already: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1327